# Create a View from custom database

Tags: views, 8

I love the features the view provides in Drupal. Sortable tables, Filters, as well as ability to use external modules like views bulk export. 
My problem is that I want to display a separate database (Call this X), using views. What would be the best way to go about it?

To get around this problem in Drupal 6, I created a content type with all fields that were in Database X, then I created view for that content type by frontend. After that I used hook_pre_render_view() to push data from X to the view. Right now I want to achieve similar results in Drupal 8. I could use this same approach but it doesn't feel very Drupally. I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a external database inorderto let Drupal Know about it:

```
$databases['external']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'custom_database',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '127.0.0.1' : 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Then you can connect to that database:

```
/*
* Switch to external db
*/
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('custom_database');

/*
* Get connection
*/
$db = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
```

Then do you stuff and don't footgrt to switch again to the standard database:

```
/*
* Switch back
*/
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
```

You can store your external database info into a content type programatically and the show in views.

Comment: Thank you, I am done with these steps. My biggest issue is what will be the best way to store external database into content type programatically, or if there is a way to bypass creation of content type and directly use views

Comment: Here is a simple example:
`code`$data = [
  'type' => 'my_content_type', 
  'title' => 'My new title', 
  'uid' => 1,
  'field_my_field' => 'my field awesome value'
];
$node = Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create($data);
$node->save();`code`

Comment: Thank you I ended up following the same technique I used in Drupal 6

Answer (score 0):

You can by using the [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) module.

> Views Database Connector is a powerful module that gives Views full
>   access to external database tables found in the settings for your
>   Drupal installation. With this module, you can setup a view around any
>   table in any database configuration. This can be extremely useful to
>   pull external data from a database to show to your users in a view.

See [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_database_connector/-/blob/8.x-1.x/README.txt) on how to use.

Comment: Thank you, module looks promising. I will keep it in mind when dealing with database and views in future. Right now, I just ended up doing the same thing I did in drupal 6